# Using Terraform to configure Azure Media Services: Specifically Content key policy with Widervine DRM

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-media-services

I'm trying to use Terraform to configure Azure Media Services and can get the main bulk working e.g. resource group, storage account etc, but can't find any documentation or examples of creating a Content key policy, with DRM (Widervine) & JWT token, I'll also need to add this json for License settings:

```
{
  "allowed_track_types": "SD_HD",
  "content_key_specs": [
    {
      "track_type": "SD",
      "security_level": 1,
      "required_output_protection": {
        "hdcp": "HDCP_NONE",
        "cgms_flags": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "policy_overrides": {
    "can_play": true,
    "can_persist": true,
    "can_renew": false,
    "rental_duration_seconds": 2592000,
    "playback_duration_seconds": 10800,
    "license_duration_seconds": 604800
  }
}
```

Current `main.tf` file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.26"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = join("", [ var.prefix, "mediaservices" ])
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = join("", [ var.prefix, "storageaccount" ])
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "sc1" {
  name                  = "archive"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "sc2" {
  name                  = "tobeprocessed"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_media_services_account" "ams" {
  name                = join("", [ var.prefix, "mediaservices" ])
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  storage_account {
    id         = azurerm_storage_account.sa.id
    is_primary = true
  }
}

output "resourceGroupName" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "containerConnectionString" {
  value = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_connection_string
}

data "azurerm_subscriptions" "available" {
}

output "subscriptionId" {
  value = data.azurerm_subscriptions.available.subscriptions[ 0 ].subscription_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for Widevine licenses here: [Media Services v3 with Widevine license template overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/widevine-license-template-overview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/offline-widevine-for-android) along with other content protection information.